# Why is Vue.js Chrome Devtools not detecting Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, vue-devtools

I have the following code with a simple working Vue.js application. But the Vue.js devtools is not responding. It was working well a few days ago, now it's not working anymore what could possibly be going wrong? when I go to [webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd), it says it is already added.

```js
let data = {
  message: 'Hello World'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#application',
  data: data
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="application">
    <input type="text" v-model="message">
    <p>The value of the input is: {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

One alternative is to set up a local web server, as the OP [already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215913/1404279).
The other - which IMHO is faster and less harassing - is letting the extension have access to file URLs, which is disabled by default.

Simply go to `chrome://extensions` and leave the "**Allow access to file URLs**" box checked for Vue.js devtools.

Sources:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#common-problems-and-how-to-fix

Comment: Does not work. Need to install Beta version of Vue dev tools.

Comment: Still the solution in 2024 - Thanks!

Answer (score 112):

I tried all of the ways presented in answers here, but none of them worked for me (neither for chrome nor for firefox).

Finally I found an answer: If you still have this problem, you can try to uninstall the current version of Vue extension and install **beta version**: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#devtools-extension

Remember to restart your browser afterwards.

Comment: This is definitely the answer for Vue 3 issues

Comment: Firefox users should get the latest beta release from here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/releases (until v6 has a stable release). The above link to the documentation goes to a specific version (which didn't work for me) rather than the latest one (which did work).

Comment: This worked the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 46):

UPDATE: 2021 May 30,

If you are using Vue 3, old dev tools versions won't work, so just use the new beta version.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg

Comment: 2021-07-05 still true, and this was the answer for me.

Comment: It's strange that the extension documentation in the web store does not clear say that it is NOT compatible with Vue 3. For ***Firefox***, there's a beta version downloadable here: https://vueschool.io/lessons/using-vue-dev-tools-with-vuejs-3

Comment: Just to add a point `DO NOT FORGET TO RESTART THE BROWSER AFTER INSTALLATION`

Comment: I didn't need to restart my browser - using Vivaldi on macOS

Answer (score 17):

To solve this, simply go to `chrome://extensions/`, scroll down to the Vue.js devtools and enable the "*Allow Access to file URLs*" by clicking on its checkbox.

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/236

Comment: also mentioned in the github readme. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#common-problems-and-how-to-fix

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue and solved it by adding

```
Vue.config.devtools = true;
```

after Vue.js import script, then take look at chrome devtools. You will see a tab called `Vue` to inspect your vue instance.

reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#devtools

Comment: Cannot set property 'devtools' of undefined

Answer (score 7):

I found out the answer, I was viewing a plain html file on my computer which was making the vue.js tool not load. I loaded up my local xampp server and ran the application from the local machine server url again and now vue.js devtools is working! :)

Comment: as a side note, I was having difficulty loading vue.js on my laravel application as well, and the trick was to run 'npm install' and then 'npm run watch' and now everything is working. I love working with Vue.js and Laravel! :)

Answer (score 4):

Also you can disable with Vue config:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#devtools

Answer (score 3):

in the extensions folder in chrome browser, under the details tab in vue devtools extension, check the box having allow access to file URLs,
this worked for me..

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Vue 3 and experiencing this issue, try installing the beta version of the Vue Devtools. It may help until the stable version gets the major refactor.

Comment: I struggled with this for ages before realising that Vue 3 isn't supported by Vue Devtools.  I also had to disable the stable version for the beta to work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue & solved it by:

1. Installing this extension [Vue Dev Tools Beta Chrome Extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg)
2. Reloading the chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

i had this problem, and i was expecting the vue-devtools to work by just including it. i had it console log the version

```
console.log("Vue Version " +Vue.version );
```

but this didnt work to actually load an instance of vue.

took me a few minutes, but once i actually created a vue instance, then it worked. this was the hello world example that made the devtools work :)

```
let data = {
  message: 'Hello World'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#application',
  data: data
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem. 
But in my case Vue.js Chrome Devtools didn't detect Vue.js because in html file was `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"/>`

I replaced it to `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>`
Now Chrome Devtools is detecting Vue.js perfectly.

Thanks for exapmle above.I use vue@2.4.4 and open my html by `file://`

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Firefox, install [the beta version of vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/releases/download/v6.0.0-beta.8/vuejs_devtools_beta-6.0.0.8-an+fx.xpi), which supports Vue 3.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30723141)

Answer (score 1):

If you have already turned on `Allow Access to file URLs` in `chrome://extensions/` -> `Vue Devtools` and it still does not work, try reinstall the Vue Devtools, might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

check if vuejs app is not embedded in an **iframe** such as in a [**storybook**](https://storybook.js.org/) app.

the hack in such a case is to work outside the parent frame working directly on the  url of your iframe and the vue [image]devtools should work fine.

Comment: I am not able to "work outsite" because I use Google Application Script and it adds iFrame on top of my web application. Any idea what to do?

Comment: how ever vue3 is not ready. work with console.log for the moment

Comment: you mean Vue3 or Vue dev plugin?

Comment: I mean vue3 at this moment

Comment: Thank you for the hint (this is also my case). Unfortunately my app only works inside an iframe (needs an other application around it), so working outside is not an option. If you or somebody else has an idea how to activate devtools inside of an iframe, it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vue in electron and I have the electron main "app" separated Vue's "app".

When in the the debugger console, typing `Vue` was giving the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined`

Here was my fix

```js
window.vue = new Vue({
  components: {
    App,
    Login,
  },
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
}).$mount('#app');
```

The work-around was **assigning** `window.Vue` so the devtool could find it.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here, and I've solved it.

If you are developing in the localhost environment and using Chrome Dev Tools then you need to give permission for the Vue.js extension to access the local files on your computer.

- Config your Vue.js tool in Chrome extensions
- Search for "Vue.js devtools"
- Click on details
- Check the "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just had compiled for production `npm run prod` - which was the issue. As I ran in dev `npm run dev`, it started recognizing Vue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vue 3 with the latest chrome extension from the extensions market (Vue.js devtools 6.5.1)
I tried to follow the answer given by @toni19 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45379603/25412
but was unable because there was no "Vue" in my app.
my app was created via the vue-cli create command.

I than added:

```
app.config.devtools = true;
```

right after the line that said:

```
const app = createApp(App)
```

in my main.js file.

and it worked for me.